# what happens if I cast (a pointer to class A) to (a pointer to its subclass B) in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

A has a static function A::create() that creates an instance of A, does some initialization, and returns a pointer to it. 
I want to create a subclass of A and have a similar create() func:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    static B* create();
    int val;
    //...
}
```

in this B::create() function I have to do the following:

```
B* B::create() {
    auto b = (B*)A::create();
    b -> val = 0;
    //...
    return b;
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? What will happen after the cast?

Follow-up: A has a protected/private constructor, How should I write B::create(), or B's constructor? I do want the vars inherited from A to have the same values as those created by A::create() would have

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: Depends on a lot of things whether it would work; but never rely on undefined behaviour.

Comment: Avoid C-style casts in C++ (use `dynamic_cast` instead). Furthermore, if your `A` and `B` classes share similar data-members then consider using mixins, composition or inheritance to avoid code-duplication.

Comment: Provide more code if you want help, e.g. class A.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? This looks like you're sort of re-inventing the Factory Pattern without knowing what you're doing (no offense--inheritance is complicated, and the C++ model is very strange!).

Comment: class A is from some lib and obviously it implements the Factory Pattern. I'm just wondering how I could subclass it. Or maybe I should just make A an variable of B.

Comment: Does `A` have a public move or copy constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cast won't do anything sensible unless `A::create()` returns a pointer to a `B` object. If `A::create()` returns a pointer to an object which isn't a `B` you have undefined behavior.

In C++ you deal with initialization of objects using constructors: the initialization of base classes is inherited and each derived can do whatever custom initialization it needs to do. Your `B::create()` would just return a suitably constructed object:

```
B::B()
    : A() // initialize base
    , val(0) {
        // other initialization
}
B* B::create() { return new B(); }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! but now B::create() won't assign values to variables inherited from A as A::created() does. My follow-up would be how to use A::create() in B::create() or B::B(), to initialize the inherited fields

Comment: You should fix `A`'s constructor so the initiaialization in `A::create()` isn't needed. If you need to use `A::create()` you can use `A* aptr = A::create(); *this = *aptr; ` in `B`'s constructor (and of course appropriately release `aptr`). I'd strongly recommend against doing so and, instead, recommend fixing `A`'s constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You could make class B a friend of A like this

```
class A {
public:
    static A* createA();
    int varA;

private:
    friend class B;    // Make B a friend so that B can use private constructor of A

    A()
    {
        cout << "In A constructor" << endl;

        varA = 5;  // Initialize members of A here
    }
};

A* A::createA()
{
    return new A;
}

class B : public A {
public:
    static B* createB();
    int varB;
private:
    B()
    {
        cout << "In B constructor" << endl;

        varB = -5;  // Initialize members of B here
    }
};

B* B::createB()
{
    return new B;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Create A" << endl;
    A* x=A::createA();
    cout << "x->varA is " << x->varA << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Create B" << endl;
    B* y=B::createB();
    cout << "y->varA is " << y->varA << endl;
    cout << "y->varB is " << y->varB << endl;
    cout << endl;

    delete x;
    delete y;
}
```

When a new B is made, the constructor of A get called automatically and the members of A will be initialized.

Output is:

```
Create A
In A constructor
x->varA is 5

Create B
In A constructor
In B constructor
y->varA is 5
y->varB is -5
```

Another way is to make the constructor of A protected instead of private.